# Парсер твиттер постов и поиск в гугле ключевого слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пробую спарсить записи твиттер за день и нужные данные сохранять в переменные (за день могут быть один, два, четыре поста), после в поиск гугл закинуть из переменной и сохранить результат в текстовом файле.
Задача такая найти за день посты и два поста с игрой вырезать игру добавить в переменную и потом в гугл.Почему у меня ошибка в отрезании строки?
Взял код немного с стековерфлоу.

```py
code = str
def twitter():
    brawser.get("https://twitter.com/Gamenew")
    textarea = brawser.find_element_by_class_name("css-901oao")
    sos = textarea(brawser.get_attribute('class-name'))
    sos = textarea.split(':', 1)[1].lstrip()  # и тут ошибка тут иногда целое предложение "="
    sos = textarea.split(' http', 1)[0].lstrip()  #ошибку тут 
    brawser.get("https://www.google.com.ua/?hl=ru")


twitter()
```

Подскажите, как можно улучшить код? Я запутался... что и как? В инете нечего не нашёл про то, как парсить твиттер ?

Answer (score 1):

В этой строке

```py
textarea = brawser.find_element_by_class_name("css-901oao")
```

бери весь селектор

```py
textarea = brawser.find_element_by_class_name("css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")
```

, а не только `css-901oao`.

Так же для парсинга лучше используй [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/bs4ru.html)

Comment: Брал так у меня пишет ошибка на данный селектор когда так делаю , а когда часть то вроде даже норм, тоже гдето ошибка может нетак строку режу?